# Cells content appearing on simulator and iPhone but not on iPad

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator, ios6

I have two quite simple custom cells in separate tableViews that since I ported my project to iOS 6 just show their content on the simulator and the iPhone but not on the iPad. What is strange is that even some static objects I added to the cell or even a coloring of the background do not show up either like there were some link to the storyboard missing that curiously only show up in the device.
What could it be and how could I check better what is going on?

Comment: do you have a separated storyboard for iPad? Had your changes made to only cell on iPhone storyboard but not on iPad storyboard?

Comment: I actually found the problem to be due to the fact CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SituationIdentifier"]; returns nil so prompting my old allocating code from the non-storyboard version to be triggered. Now my problem is why the function return nil instead of the prototype cell in the storyboard. I checked many entry on the internet but none of them seems to apply to my case.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact I was testing two different localizations in the simulator and iPad by being tricked by a string I forgot translating. The problem boiled down to the the storyboard returning me an empty prototype so bringing my program to run an old piece of code that in that case created a new (empty) cell. Why the storyboard returned nil when asked for a prototype cell is still unclear; yet once I found that one localization worked, I copied that configuration to the other ones and everything returned back to order.